# How to split development env file and production env file with docker compose?

Tags: django, docker, nginx, docker-compose, environment-variables

I have dockerized django application with nginx. And I have two env files: one for development and one for production. The contents of the env files are the credentials of the database.

But apparently, the credentials that are inside the prodduction env file are not executed.

My folder structure looks like this:

```
root 
 - welzijn
 -admin
```

So when I put the env files with names: .env and prod.env in the root folder, it doesn't work.

But when I put the .env file with the credentials of production in the welzijn folder it works. And even when I put the file prod.env in the folder welzijn it also doesn't work

I really scratch my head over this.

So this is the dockerfile:

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.9-alpine3.13

# ENV PATH="/scripts:${PATH}"

# set work directory
# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY ./requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
COPY ./scripts /scripts

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
EXPOSE 8000


# install psycopg2 dependencies
ARG DEV=false
RUN python -m venv /py && \
    /py/bin/pip install --upgrade pip && \
    apk add --update --no-cache postgresql-client jpeg-dev && \
    apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .tmp-build-deps \
    build-base postgresql-dev musl-dev zlib zlib-dev linux-headers && \
    /py/bin/pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt && \
    apk del .tmp-build-deps && \
    adduser \
    --disabled-password \
    --no-create-home \
    django-user 


ENV PATH="/scripts:/py/bin:$PATH"
USER django-user
COPY . .
# run entrypoint.sh

CMD ["run.sh"]
```

and docker-compose-deploy.yml file:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  web:
    image: crdierenwelzijn.azurecr.io/web1
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    restart: always

    command: gunicorn DierenWelzijn.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/usr/src/app/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/usr/src/app/media
    expose:
      - 8000
    env_file:
      - prod.env

  proxy:
    image: crdierenwelzijn.azurecr.io/proxy1
    build:
      context: ./proxy
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - web
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/home/app/media

volumes:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
```

and my nginx.conf file looks like:

```
upstream DierenWelzijn {
    server web:8000;
}

server {

    listen 80;
    server_name https://dierenwelzijndocker.azurewebsites.net; 

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://DierenWelzijn;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;       
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;                
        client_max_body_size    10M;       
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/app/staticfiles/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /home/app/media/;
    }
}
```

And part of settings.py file:

```
from os import environ
from pathlib import Path
import os
import dotenv

dotenv.read_dotenv()




BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/checklist/


SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
DEBUG = bool(int(os.environ.get('DEBUG', 0)))

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '192.168.1.135',
                 'dockerdierenwelzijn.azurewebsites.net', 'www.dockerdierenwelzijn.azurewebsites.net']
ALLOWED_HOSTS.extend(
    filter(
        None,
        os.environ.get('ALLOWED_HOSTS', '').split(" "),
    )
)
# SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO", "https")
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    "https://dockerdierenwelzijn.azurewebsites.net", "http://192.168.1.135:8000"]
# CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = os.listdir('CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS')


# Application definition
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

SECURE_CROSS_ORIGIN_OPENER_POLICY = None



DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        "ENGINE": 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        "HOST": os.environ.get("DB_HOST"),
        "NAME": os.environ.get("DB_NAME"),
        "USER": os.environ.get('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DB_PASS'),
        "PORT": os.environ.get("DB_PORT", "5432"),
    }
}
```

So I have the prod.env file now in the root folder. But this doesn't work.

And also the strange thing about this is when I delete the prod.env file from the root folder and I try to build the docker container I get an error that the file doesn't exist.

Question: what I have to change so that the prod.env file be executed?

Comment: How does your application read its settings?  If the application itself is looking for a file named `.env`, the one you `COPY` into your image gets used.  Compose `env_file:` will set actual environment variables, which in Python you'd read via `os.environ` and similar mechanisms.

Comment: @DavidMaze. I have updated the post with the settings.py file.

Comment: But what I have to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, it seems like the issue is with how the environment variables from your `prod.env` file are being read and utilized in your Docker setup. Here are some steps and considerations to help resolve this issue:

- Ensure that the path specified in the `env_file` directive in your `docker-compose-deploy.yml` file correctly points to your `prod.env` file. If the file is in the root directory, the path should be correct as `- prod.env`.
- The `prod.env` file needs to be within the build context of your Docker image. If you're building your image from the root directory (as indicated by `context: ./` in your `docker-compose-deploy.yml`), then placing `prod.env` in the root should work.
- In your `settings.py`, you're using `dotenv.read_dotenv()`. This function looks for `an .env` file by default. If you're using a different filename like prod.env, you need to specify the path explicitly:

```
dotenv.read_dotenv(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'prod.env'))
```

*Ensure that this code is executed before any environment variables are accessed.*

- In your Dockerfile, you're copying the entire project directory into the image. This should include your prod.env file if it's in the root. However, note that the ENV instructions in the Dockerfile set environment variables at build time, not runtime. Your Django app reads them at runtime.
- Ensure that your volume mounts in the `docker-compose-deploy.yml` file do not unintentionally overwrite the directory where prod.env is located.
- After building the image, run a container and exec into it to check if the prod.env file is present at the expected location.
- Temporarily add a command in your Dockerfile to `cat` the `prod.env` file after copying it, to make sure it's being copied correctly.
- Use `docker compose config` to verify that your compose file is correctly configured and includes the prod.env file.
- Check the permissions of the prod.env file to ensure it's readable by the user running the Django application inside the container.
- Every time you make changes to the `prod.env` file or Docker configuration, ensure to rebuild your containers with `docker compose up --build`.

Comment: docker-compose is considered old technology, docker compose should be used preferably.

Comment: In most modern setups with Docker Compose v2, both commands are likely to point to the same Docker Compose v2 functionality, but this isn't universally true, especially in environments where Docker Compose v1 is still installed. You are right; `docker compose` should be used preferably and I edited my answer. @ElvinJafarov

Comment: Oke, But I am using docker compose and not docker-compose: docker compose -f docker-compose-deploy.yml build. Oke, I will try to put the docker-compose-deploy file in a seperate folder.